Convenience formula for integral on product space
Let $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ equipped with some product $\sigma$-algebra be a product space.
Suppose $\mu$ is any positive measure (not necessarily any product measure) on $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ and $f:\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is any measurable function. Is there  any convenient formula decomposing the integral as integration first on $\Omega_1$ then on $\Omega_2$ using slices (of $f$ and of $\mu$):
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2}f(\omega_1,\omega_2)d\mu(\omega_1,\omega_2)
\end{equation*}
My trouble here is mainly a notational one, I would like a formula with notation as convenient as possible. What I can find online is mainly the notation for decomposing $f$ but not decomposing $\mu$.  A special case $f(\omega_1,\omega_2) = f_1(\omega_1)f_2(\omega_2)$ would  also be accepted if things are any easier in this case.

Maybe what you are after is the theory of disintegration. As a starting point you may check out Wikipedia: Disintegration Theorem.

This seems to be what I am looking for. Thank you!
